# CSS / Javascript: hidden div does not take full width after being shown

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have an HTML page with the following divs that are being filled with a chart using Highcharts. 
By default one of them is hidden and is then displayed based on selections on the page.

When I show the div programmatically it only takes a small part of the screen width but when I show it by default, i.e. without the CSS hiding then it takes the full screen width (which is what I want).

Can someone tell me how I can set the divs to keep full screen width or how to reset this after being shown ?

**My divs:**

```
<div id="containerR" style="height:600px; margin:0 auto; min-width:300px;"></div>
<div id="containerC" style="height:600px; margin:0 auto; min-width:300px; display:none"></div>
```

**My JS function:**

```
$('#viewC').on('click', function() {
    $('#viewR').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $('#viewC').addClass('btn-primary');
    $('#containerR').hide();
    $('#containerC').show();
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: I believe you need to hide the chart only after it is drawn

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I cannot re-apply the CSS via JavaScript afterwards ?

Comment: Problem is highChart probably draws according to available space, but if its hidden it messes up its calculation. Even if you show it later and set the width, the chart has already been drawn with the other size. You need to unhide it when you draw the chart, and after that you can hide it again

Comment: Confirmed, it works well your way. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your proyect

Comment: Thanks - do you want to post this as an answer ?

Comment: Perhaps try using visibility:hidden; instead of display:none; and see if that works too. Whereas display:none; actually makes other objects fall into the space where the element used to be, visibility:hidden; just hides the object, but still allows it to take up space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is highChart probably draws according to available space, but if its hidden it messes up its calculation. Even if you show it later and set the width, the chart has already been drawn with the other size.

You need to unhide it when you draw the chart, and after that you can hide it again